# Error clearing cache / composer install - SensioFrameworkExtraBundle not found in kernel.php line 33

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, composer-php

I face an issue since last Friday. Everything was working fine on my project and then friday when deploying:
after

```
$> php bin/console cache:clear
```

My Symfony project doesn't work anymore. I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioFrameworkExtraBundle" from namespace "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /Users/dam/Development/Alara/rayflex/git/rayborn/src/Kernel.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/dam/Development/Alara/rayflex/git/rayborn/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(492): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
#1 /Users/dam/Development/Alara/rayflex/git/rayborn/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(132): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
#2 /Users/dam/Development/Alara/rayflex/git/rayborn/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(64): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 /Users/dam/Development/Alara/rayflex/git/rayborn/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /Users/dam/ in /Users/dam/Development/Alara/rayflex/git/rayborn/src/Kernel.php on line 33
```

- I tried to delete my vendor and reinstall same error
- I tried a composer selfupdate && composer update
- I Also tried to put the use in kernel.php...

Still nothing

I took an old tag of my project who was working fine Some month back. Same error..

Comment: Have you also tried a `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: Have you tried `bin/console cache:warmup` or `bin/console cache:warmup dev` ?

Comment: Can you show the content of your `composer.json` file?

Comment: Yes i tries cache:warmup and cache:warmup dev but i found the solution..

I just reinstall sensioFrameWorkBundle and it work well now ..

I can't explain why it has happen (i can redo the bug by checking out one local commit)..

Answer (score 0):

I have Fix my problem on reinstalling SenSio Bundle

```
$ composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

I can't explain why, it was already installed and in the composer.json before ..

Thank for your help !